# Highcharts - how to align two charts on a same line

Tags: javascript, highcharts

What will be the best way to align two charts on a same line? The thing is that I have different number of legend items and the height differs from one another. I've tried playing around the legend position, but it doesn't seem to work for me

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can set maxHeight parameter per each legend, then always this object have the same size. As a result your chart will be aligned.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.maxHeight